# Jenkins auto update dropdown menu

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to automatically update the dropdown menu from a build in jenkins based on the files within a folder. For example if a new folder called R10 is added to a specific folder I would like Jenkins to show it in it's job selection.

Tried to add it directly to the config.xml of the job but it doesn't get updated into Jenkins

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not straight forward, your requirement needs a custom wrapper(script) which checks folder "new folder" and adds any new folder which is getting created in "new folder" to job's build configuration and then to save the configuration.

if your editing/directly adding the option/name to config.xml i doubt it is getting saved/consumed in the build.

Answer which worked :`CRUMB=$(curl -s 'admin:pass@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(‌​//…) curl -X POST -H "$CRUMB" admin:pass@localhost:8080/reload`

Comment: I thought there would be a way that you can add it to the xml file and after do a reload of the xml file from jenkins. Once i restart Jenkins it works but I would like to know if there is a way just to reload a particular Job

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do it. updating xml files and restarting jenkins is not a good idea, because it would be painful in long run,rather write a groovy script to update and save the target job.So the next run of your job will pick new configuration without even restarting jenkins. Option 2 would be to use jenkins cli jar and updating job,option 3 use rest api (post method ) to update job

Comment: Used option3 :) 
 CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://admin:pass@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
 curl -X POST -H "$CRUMB" http://admin:pass@localhost:8080/reload

Comment: @Dusty is it working ? or do u need additional help here ?

Comment: @Dusty added you comment as an answer since it worked for you , credits to you as well :)